# Using Multi-Platform Projects in CocoaPods target framework

Tags: cocoapods, xcode13

I am working on a project with multiple platforms (iOS, tvOS). This project has a target, with `Allow Multi-Platform Builds` enabled.

```
target 'TestTarget' do
  project 'TestTarget/TestTarget'

  pod 'SomePod' => '~> 9.2.1'

  platform :ios, '12.3'

end
```

This works for iOS now, but tvOS won't compile anymore, because it doesn't link the framework properly. I can only set one `platform` in the `Podfile` for that target, but need to set `tvOS` as well.

Comment: From Xcode UI or xcodebuild?

Comment: I try to compile it from Xcode UI.